# Тыква есть полезный продукт, и только полезный(,) — вне зависимости от того

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Тыква есть полезный продукт, и только полезный(,) — вне зависимости от того, какие есть у тебя аллергии (если она, конечно, не тыквенная).

Comment: _И только полезный_ — присоединение, следовательно нужно обособить с двух сторон, поэтому запятая нужна.

Comment: Нужно рассматривать предложение как цельную конструкцию, а не по отдельным частям.  Выбор знака на стыке фраз всегда проблема,  Предложение такой структуры вряд ли найдешь в правилах, поэтому решать надо самим.  Но в любом случае ссылка на правило должна быть.  У меня она есть.

Comment: @Sharon Посмотрите последний ответ: https://gramota.ru/spravka?page=4 Сомневаюсь, что, рассматривая как целую конструкцию и решая по блокам, ставилась бы запятая и тире. А здесь двухстороннее обособление запятыми, в том числе перед тире.

Comment: Это сочетание двух разных знаков, а не единый знак.

Comment: Читателю без разницы, что это такое. Единый знак и сочетание знаков выглядит одинаково, и это предупреждение об увеличенной паузе. Решение по блокам указано в правилах, и именно это решение дает нам понимание о целом предложении, а не о его фрагментах.  Для чего нужна пунктуация? Чтобы наилучшим образом выразить семантику сообщения. И это бесконечное списывание примеров (а как там у них) тоже не выход. Каждое предложение конкретно. Ссылку давайте на правило,  а не на ответы Грамоты.

Comment: @Sharon Во-первых, отает Грамоты ничем не хуже. Во-вторых, даже у Лопатина наптсано, цитирую, «...**при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании**». Даже Лопатин упомянул, что внутренние знаки сохраняются (столько лет пользовались и не заметили или вам пофиг?). Это раз. Розенталь пишет: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175. «В большинстве случаев запятая и тире ставятся __на собственном основании__». И описал случаи. Присоединительный оборот не описан, но подходит. Суету наводит не Лопатин, а неправильное его понимание.

Comment: Хотя я, вероятнее, зря это написал, потому что я вас знаю: вы останетесь на своем, неверном мнении, несмотря на все доказательства.

Comment: @Sharon И пожалуйста. Не буду вам больше мешать; возможно, это последняя капля. Точно ухожу, потому что люди принимают такие ответы (смотреть сложно!). У самого опытного человека такое понимание, к тому же доказательства вас никакие не берут. Вам повезло с репутацией, потому что чем выше репутация, тем вы сильнее, а следовательно, спорящий с вами уйдет, а не вы. Вам удалось меня выгнать. Опытны вы только по репутации. Оставляю вас в полной гармонии, где никто вам мешать не будет, устанавливайте свои правила, давайте свои ответы. Пусть все их принимают. Для вас анархия окончена. До не встречи!

Comment: Ох уж эти мужчины!  У многих женский характер)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Тыква есть полезный продукт, **и только полезный** — // **вне зависимости от того,** какие есть у тебя аллергии (если она, конечно, не тыквенная).*

1. **Сложный синтаксис**, поэтому решаем задачу методом блоков **[по Лопатину](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).**

В первом блоке есть присоединительный оборот "и только полезный", что затрудняет выбор **на границе** блоков. Возможные варианты — **единый знак или тире**.

2. Выбираем **тире**,  так как обе части связаны по смыслу: полезность продукта оценивается по отношению к аллергии. Присоединительного характера нет, и вторая часть входит в **основное** сообщение. Здесь достаточно тире, чтобы обозначить нужную **паузу**.
3. При использовании **единого знака** (запятая и тире) второе сообщение будет рассматриваться как самостоятельное, без обозначения **достаточной связи** с первой частью.